# Azure Data Lake Gen 2 Integration with DataFactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I am trying to connect data lake gen2 with data factory v2 where we need to add the user through Add user Wizard in data lake . But we couldnt see that option in this and we are not able to connect to data lake gen 2 from data factory . Please help .Let us know what is different approach than Gen1 for Gen2 in connecting to ADF V2.

THank you,
Sashank Pappu

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "where we need to add the user through Add user Wizard in data lake". Currently, Data Factory V2 supports connecting to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 via:

- account key
- service principal
- managed identity

To create a linked service in ADF, create a new dataset and choose Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2.
[image]

When creating the linked service, choose your authentication method. If you go with account key, your url will look like `https://<accountname>.dfs.core.windows.net`. It's easiest to use the From Azure subscription to find your account rather than typing it in.

If you choose Service Principal, you will need to have [registered your app in AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app#register-your-application-with-an-azure-ad-tenant) and granted the service princpal Storage Blob Data Reader and/or Storage Blob Data Contributor role.

If you use Managed Service Identity, grab the service identity application ID from the window right underneath where you chose your storage account while creating your linked service. 
[image]

Then give it appropriate permissions. Go to the Azure Portal and open your storage account. Choose Access Control (IAM). Click on Role assignments and then click the Add button. Select Storage Blob Data Reader (or Storage Blob Data Writer if necessary). Leave Assign access to set on Azure AD user, group, or service principal. Paste in the service identity (for MSI, for Service Principal, paste in the application ID) in the Select box. It will search and return an identity with the name of your data factory. Select it and click save.

[Here's a good link that explains all the details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage)

Comment: I have followed your steeps but when I paste the `Service identity application ID` it doesn't shows the datafactory. Do you have something else to note?